# Correlation of motion or movement timeseries

Tags: time-series, correlation

Assuming we have tracked the movement of a group of people, is it possible to detect, if one person follows another? Or if even a group of people follows one person?

To be more specific: In a crowd of approx. 500 moving people, I want to identify "leaders", which direct the movement of people around, or identify at least groups of people which behave similar. 
Latter one is more a spatio-temporal clustering, for which I haven't found a working approach so far.

The usual timeseries analyses I know fail, as there are two dimensions per timepoint and individuum (X,Y coordinates).

Comment: Could you describe your data?

Comment: The data is derived from 200 image frames of a video. I can extract and track successfully objects. So for each track I have a sequence of 3-tuples (X,Y,t), meaning the X,Y coordinates and time point. In total there are about 500 to 700 tracks.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem. You want to know if there's a leader in the movement pattern observed, correct?

Idea: Granger causality type analysis on the position and velocity time series could do the trick. If someone is always leading the position and velocity, then they could be considered the leader.